# Overload using Enum types

Tags: java, enums, overloading

Is it possible to have several enum types:

```
public enum Parameter {
    XMETRIC, YMETRIC,..
```

and have a method overload using those types?

```
method(Parameter.XMETRIC type) {}
method(Parameter.YMETRIC type) {}
```

I know you can use switch cases and get the same result but I find it strange this isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum constants are not types, they are variables referencing instances of the corresponding `enum` type. So, no, you can't use them as parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

With enums one may override methods per enum constant. Also one may use constructors with parameters.

```
public enum Parameter {
    XMETRIC() {
        @Override
        public void method() {
        }
    },
    YMETRIC() {
        @Override
        public void method() {
        }
    },
    ...
    ZMETRIC();

    private Parameter() {
    }

    public void method() {
    }
}
```

In java 8 lambdas may be used:

```
public enum Parameter {
    XMETRIC(() -> { System.out.println(Parameter.this); }),
    YMETRIC(() -> { ... }),
    ...
    ZMETRIC(null);

    private final Runnable method;

    private Parameter(Runnable method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public void callMethod() {
        if (method != null) {
            method.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ENUM itself is the *type*, however the constants are not.

Say you have:

```
enum Roles{
    GUEST,
    USER,
    ADMIN;
}
```

You may pass in `Roles` as a parameter like so - `public void someMethod(Roles role)`.

Case example

```
//Some code
someMethod(Roles.ADMIN);
```

---

To explicitly answer your question, no that is not possible. The constants can not be represented as datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, java doesn't have runtime method overloading. 
So there is no way to switch between 1 method and another based on the runtime class of a parameter.

Secondly, runtime type overloading doesn't work based on the value of a variable.

So in short, no. you cannot have

```
public void someMethod(1)
public void someMethod(2)
```

that trigger on 1 or 2 respectively. 
Just like you can't do this using enums.

The only type of overloading java has is compile-time.

given:

```
public class A {
}
public class B {
}

public void someMethod(A a) { System.out.println("a"); }
public void someMethod(B b) { System.out.println("a"); }
```

the following calls will yield these results:

```
A a = new A();
A secretB = new B();
B b = new B();

someMethod(a); // prints a
someMethod(secretB); // prints a
someMethod(b); // prints b

someMethod(null); // doesn't compile, you have to cast so A or B
someMethod((B) null); // prints b
```